# Newbie stuck.. What is this pop up/sliding menu called? Video preview included

Tags: ios, xcode

Hello I'm trying to recreate this type of menu that pops up/slides up when a uibutton is pressed.

Here is a preview from the Muzik app [sample video](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/45732440/20041DB9-AAE2-4FEF-8EE0-FC5AB9152160.avi) I just do not know if it is an action sheet or something else your assistance is greatly appreciated. I'm new to Xcode and what I know thus far is self taught. I cannot figure out the correct name for this type of menu.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably just a view with a partially-transparent background color and some labels or customized buttons as subviews.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea on the slide animation?

Comment: *[UIView Class Reference: Animations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006816-CH3-SW131)*

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to that in UIKit would be a UIActionSheet. Customizing one to look exactly like that will be challenging... you're better off just making your own custom view.